# jdbc ResultSet.get<DataType> returns null

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-redshift

So I have the following issue.
I have a Java application that connects to a Redshift-DB via jdbc. Executing a simple SELECT-query yields a ResultSet that is not null (I checked).

Now, when I try to extract data from this ResultSet, the method will sometimes return null, even though a previous ResultSet.wasnull() returns false and a manual check in the database also reveals that the record in question does not contain a null value for that attribute.

Sample code:

```
    private void test(){

    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;
    String getTable = "SELECT * from myTable"; //
    try(PreparedStatement prep = myConnection.prepareStatement(getTable
            , ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY
            )){
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while(rs.next()){                               // loop over all rows
            for(int col = 1; col <= columns; col++){
                if(rs.wasNull())
                    System.out.println("NULL Value detected!");

                System.out.println("Column Name: " + rsmd.getColumnName(col));
                System.out.println("Column value: " + rs.getString(col));
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works most of the time, except for some records the rs.getString(col) will just result in a null (even though the data type in the DB is CHAR or VARCHAR). This does not necessarily happen for all columns (I've seen it happen that a couple of columns were read and printed correctly, until eventually, a null appeared, even though wasnull() returned false.

So far, I have observed this behaviour for ResultSet.getString(), ResultSet.getDate() and ResultSet.getTimestamp(), but never when extracting any sort of number (getInt()...). In all these cases, I checked the DB to make sure the jdbc-method matches the data type.

I tried using different driver versions, I tried using rs.getBytes(col) instead, but the result remains the same: I just cannot get rid of those nulls.

I also successfully did an UNLOAD-operation, unloading the troublesome table to S3 and manually checking the exported csv files. The UNLOAD runs without any issue, the CSVs look fine to me (all values as expected).

Now I could of course manually handle those "unwanted NULLs" by skipping the records in which they occur, but I'd rather avoid glossing over this error like  that without understanding its cause.

So my question would be:

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in my code?
Is there a known issue with jdbc / Redshift that could cause this?
Can someone maybe point me to some sources or give me some ideas on what else I could try?

Answer (score 1):

From the javadoc of [`ResultSet.wasNull()`](http://Please%20read%20the%20javadoc%20of%20[%60ResultSet.wasNull()%60](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#wasNull()).%20You%20should%20use%20it%20**after**%20reading%20a%20column.%20It%20is%20only%20useful%20for%20pr):

> Reports whether the last column read had a value of SQL `NULL`. Note
>   that you must first call one of the getter methods on a column to try
>   to read its value and then call the method `wasNull` to see if the
>   value read was SQL `NULL`.
>
> Returns:
>      `true` if the last column value read was SQL `NULL` and false otherwise

In other words, you should use it **after** reading a column. Be aware that for object types it makes no sense to call `wasNull`, as the object getters will already return `null`.

This method is intended to be used when reading columns using the primitive getters (like `getInt()`), because those will return `0` for `null` values. You can then use `wasNull()` to check if the value was really `0` or actually `null`.

In other words, change your code to:

```
while(rs.next()){                               // loop over all rows
    for(int col = 1; col <= columns; col++){
        String value = rs.getString(col);
        if(value == null)
            System.out.println("NULL Value detected!");

        System.out.println("Column Name: " + rsmd.getColumnName(col));
        System.out.println("Column value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Or, if you really want to use `wasNull()` (but really, you shouldn't!):

```
while(rs.next()){                               // loop over all rows
    for(int col = 1; col <= columns; col++){
        String value = rs.getString(col);
        if(rs.wasNull())
            System.out.println("NULL Value detected!");

        System.out.println("Column Name: " + rsmd.getColumnName(col));
        System.out.println("Column value: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have read the Javadoc more carefully. However, the point remains that I manually checked the fields in question in the DB, and there I also found that no NULL was present, e.g. I would find a perfectly reasonable DATE value where rs.getDate() simply returned null.

Comment: @Flo I suggest your post a **new** question that provides a [mcve] that reproduces that problem. I'd be really surprised if it was a bug in the Redshift driver. I'd sooner expect something like using a different database or table then you have checked.

Comment: I quite literally had the application spit out the used SELECT via System.out.println() and pasted that into sql Workbench, using the fully qualified name of the table. I also copy-pasted the DB-url and made sure to use the same credentials. I don't see how I could have checked the wrong DB / table.

Comment: In any case, for a working minimal example, I would also need to provide a table including data that causes this behaviour, and I haven't been able to identify any characteristic data pattern that I can connect to these weird NULLs. To me it seems completely random, but when I set up my own test table, I somehow seem unable to insert data that causes these "unwanted NULLs".

Comment: @Flo In any case, I can't address your Redshift specific problems. I have no experience with that. I just answered what was caused by incorrect use of the JDBC api.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate pointing out my JDBC related mistake (hence my upvote), I'll see if I find a way to deal with the other issue(s).